# How do I sucessfully login to Instagram by HttpRequest in C# [.NET]?

Tags: c#, winforms, authentication, httprequest, instagram

I am curretly facing the problem that i cannot successfully login to instagram by using HttpRequest [.NET] in C#.

I looked up the http headers in fiddler, tamper data and live http headers.

I use a CookieContainer for saving the cookies and transfer them to the login function but still not logged in.

I have researched the last few months to solve the problem. At the current moment i am really stuck.

Here is "my" sourcecode, to be specific i googled a lot and tried to get the best out of all researches.

```
    private CookieCollection _cookies = new CookieCollection();

    private void getCookies()
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://instagram.com/accounts/login"); // "https://instagram.com/accounts/login/" here is successful --> no 403
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(_cookies);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        _cookies = response.Cookies;
        Console.WriteLine(_cookies.Count);
        foreach (var tmpin _cookies)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tmp.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void login()
    {
        string getUrl = "https://instagram.com/accounts/login"; // "https://instagram.com/accounts/login/" will create error 403
        string postData = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}", "xyz", "123");
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(_cookies);
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        getRequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
        getRequest.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
        getRequest.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        getRequest.Referer = "https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?next=/accounts/edit/";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
        newStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(sourceCode);
        } 
    }
```

//***********************************************************************************************//

The next function would be my second try:

```
    private void login2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_cookies[0].Value);
        string PostData = String.Format("csrftoken={0}&username=xyz&password=123!", _cookies[0].Value);

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://instagram.com/accounts/login");
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.KeepAlive = true;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        req.CookieContainer.Add(_cookies);
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
        req.Headers["Accept-Language"] = "de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
        req.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostData);
        req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        using (Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Flush();
            dataStream.Close();
        }

        string s;
        using (HttpWebResponse webResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream datastream = webResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream))
                {
                    s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        if (s.Contains("xyz"))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Logged in");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not");
        }

    }
```

Both login functions require getCookies()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Instagram is protected for these kind of events. The program you are writing is acting like some kind of a bot. Isn't there an api you can use?

Comment: Of course I use an api, but to get an access_token, which is necessary for using the api, one has to login to instagram and then he will be redirected to the "authorize" url, which responds with a code. 

At the moment i am using an external webBrowser object (winforms) and the user has to visit the page and has to login there.
But it doesn't please me.
That's why i am asking for another method like httpRequest.